# DataTable decorated with Bootstrap on inactive Tab Has Narrow Header

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am using DataTables with Bootstrap and got it all working.  Then I needed a table in a tab and when I do this the table header starts narrow, just fitting to the width of the header text.  If the tab is active when the page is shown, the table looks great.  You can see an [example](http://www.greggbolinger.com/DT/index.html) of what I mean.  Tab 1 looks fine.  Tab 2 has the narrow header.

If I enable sorting and click a column on Tab 2 the header expands to the appropriate width, but always starts narrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your header columns are initialized with `width: 0px`.  I assume because they aren't rendered (Tab 2 has `display: none`).

If you include the bootstrap.js library you could try initializing your DataTable on tab switching:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function (e) {
   e.target // activated tab
   e.relatedTarget // previous tab
   $('#table-b').dataTable({ ... });
});
```

Comment: Yea, I've done that.  Had to do some rigging to detect if the table has been rendered yet because DataTables will complain about re-rendering itself.  So this is a good hack, but not a solution.  Thanks.

Comment: Marked this as the answer unless/until a non-hack solution surfaces.

Answer (score 3):

What I found that happens to work is the Following:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function (e) {
e.target // activated tab 
e.relatedTarget // previous tab 
var table = $.fn.dataTable.fnTables(true);
 if ( table.length > 0 ) {
 $(table).dataTable().fnAdjustColumnSizing();
 }
});
```

I was really racking my brain on this one, however since it only checks once if the table has been initialized after the Bootstrap Tab has been clicked, you shouldn't be pestered with the DataTable reinitialization Alert.

*I'm not certain if this will work with BootStrap 1, however, I do know it works with BootStrap 2.*

Answer (score 2):

In bootstrap 3.x you can use this code:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    e.target // activated tab 
    e.relatedTarget // previous tab 
    var table = $.fn.dataTable.fnTables(true);
    if (table.length > 0) {
        $(table).dataTable().fnAdjustColumnSizing();
    }
});
```

More info at: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: I'm using Bootstrap 1, not 2: but it might work for you.

After much trial and error, this is the function I added to get the dataTable to redraw when the correct tab was clicked (no complaining about the redraw, either):

```
$(function() {   
    $('a[href="#tab2"]').live('click', function () {
     var oTable = $('#dataTables4').dataTable();
      oTable.fnDraw();
    }); 
});
```

Here's my dataTable code. Note the callback which ensures that the table will be completely drawn before it is displayed:

```
    $('#loadingT').show();
    $('#dataTables4').dataTable({


   "fnDrawCallback":function(){
                $('#loadingT').hide();
                 $(".dataListT").fadeIn(2000);

                        },   

            "bPaginate": false,
             "bScrollCollapse": true,
                "sScrollY": "305px",


            "aaSorting": [[ 2, "desc" ],[3, "desc"]],
            "sDom": "<'row'<'span16'f>>t<'row'i<'span8'><'span8'>>",


         "aoColumns": [
                        { "bSortable": false },
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        { "iDataSort": 6 },
                        {"bVisible": false},
                        {"bVisible": false},
                        null
                    ],
        "fnFooterCallback": function ( nRow, aaData, iStart, iEnd, aiDisplay ) {


                           /* Calculate the total transactions on this page */
                          var total = 0;
                         for ( var i=iStart ; i<iEnd ; i++ )
                         {
                              total += aaData[ aiDisplay[i] ][7]* 1;
                          }

                               var nCells = nRow.getElementsByTagName('th');
                                nCells[1].innerHTML = total;
                                $(nCells[1]).formatCurrency({negativeFormat:'%s-%n'});


                                            }





        }).rowGrouping({
                        iGroupingColumnIndex: 1,
                       sGroupingColumnSortDirection: "desc",
                       iGroupingOrderByColumnIndex: 2

                    });
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I simply set all tabs to active, and on document ready, removed the active class for all tabs except the first.
Very ugly hack, but I haven't been able to figure out a better way